# Dynamic Checkbox wont do uncheck work

Tags: jquery, dynamic

Hi I am dynamically adding checkboxes to a form with the followng code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <?php foreach ($checks as $che) : ?>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->checkbox($che, array('class' => $che, 'name' => $che)); ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

which works fine and then in jquery im trying to do something depending on whether its checked or not with the following code:

```
$('.Variables:checkbox').live('click', (function()
{
    if($('.' +  this.name).prop("checked", true))
    {
        $("#accordion").find('h3').filter(':contains('+this.name+')').show();

    }
    else if($('.' +  this.name).prop("checked", false))
    {
        $("#accordion").find('h3').filter(':contains('+this.name+')').hide();
    }
}));
```

The first time i click the checkbox it works fine and the h3 tag appears but then when i try click it again it doesn't hide like it should.

any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CakePHP.  The issue is with either the HTML, the Javascript, or both. (Please post the generated HTML code, not the PHP that generates it).

Comment: `live()` is actually deprecated and it would be wise to move to `on()`

Comment: Check the CSS on the `h3`, it might be overlapping the checkbox so the click event never hits your node.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it but thanks for your replies

```
$('.Variables:checkbox').on('click', (function()
{
    if($(this).prop("checked"))
    {
        $("#accordion").find('h3').filter(':contains('+this.name+')').show();  
    }
    else
    {
        $("#accordion").find('h3').filter(':contains('+this.name+')').hide();
    }
}));
```